# Nested collection resolve in Laravel Resource

Tags: php, laravel, api, collections, resources

I've got two one-to-many relationships in Laravel, where Cities(id, name, region_id) <- Regions(id, name, country_id) <- Countries(id, name).

I'd need to create a Resource that can return all the Cities in all the Regions in a given Country, like:

```
"results": [
{
    "region": 1,
    "name": "Abruzzo",
    "cities": {
        {"id": 1,
         "name": "Aaa"},
         {"id": 2,
         "name": "Aab"},
     },
 },
        {
    "region": 2,
    "name": "Basilicata",
    "cities": {
        {"id": 1,
         "name": "Baa"},
         {"id": 2,
         "name": "Bab"},

    },
 }
```

for just one level of relationship, i would create a RegionResource, a RegionsResource and use the Resolve() method inside a, let's say, ResultsResource, like:

```
'regions' => (new RegionsResource($country))->resolve(),
```

but I don't seem to be able to do it in a recursive way for both the levels. Could anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Solved thanks to my colleague. Here's the code:

```
    $cities = collect();

    $regions->each(function($region) use(&$cities) {
        $cities->push($region->cities);
    });
```